# Numerical method for Non smooth Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am considering the following "differential equation"

\begin{equation*}
 \frac{dy}{dx} =  \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f_1(x)+g(x) & \quad x < 0 \\
            f_2(x)+g(x) & \quad x \geq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
with $y(3)=0$,$f_1(0)=f_2(0)$, and $g(x)$ is a continuously differentiale function . Specifically $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two parts of a piecewise linear continuous function. Hence the right hand side is Lipschitz continuous in the whole domain . I am considering the following scheme to solve for $y(x)$

Step 1: Solve for $\frac{dy}{dy}=f_2(x)+g(x)$ with $y(4)=0$. Lets call this solution $y_2(x)$. Then save the value $y_2(0)$.
Step 2: Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}=f_1(x)+g(x)$ with $y(0)=y_2(0)$. Lets call this solution $y_1(x)$

Then our proposed solution is
\begin{equation*}
 y(x)=  \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            y_1(x) & \quad x < 0 \\
            y_2(x) & \quad x \geq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

I can not see a problem with this proposed method. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Thats totally fine. Its always allowed to split the domain into multiple regions. Many numerical methods do this even for completely smooth problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the right side is continuous, such a kink will only have minimal consequences for the solver accuracy.

With a solver with adaptive step-size, any such discontinuity in the function or lower derivatives can lead to a dramatic reduction in the step size when approaching this point. In practice I have yet to see an overly dramatic example.

Some solvers have an option for critical points that then become guaranteed nodes for the internal step size control, with no evaluations across such points during the method steps. If that is the case for your solver, giving the singularity points as critical points implements your strategy without any further effort.

With any less sophisticated solver, your described strategy will lead to a minimal number of points generated by the step-size control. It could be helpful to pass the last step size of the first segment as the initial step size for the second segment.